# react-pdf-highlighter ReferenceError: document is not defined in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Trying to add pdf highlighter feature in a Next Js project using [react-pdf-highlighter](https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter)
I'm getting many errors like

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> at eval (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/web/pdf_viewer.js:1644:3)
>
> node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/web/pdf_viewer.js (1649:0) @ eval
> unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: window is not defined
> at eval (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/web/pdf_viewer.js:1644:3)

Here below my component source code for reference. How can I fix these error above

```
"use client"
import { useAuth } from '@/providers/auth.provider';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Sidebar } from './sidebar';
import { AreaHighlight, Highlight, IHighlight, NewHighlight, PdfHighlighter, PdfLoader, Popup, Tip } from 'react-pdf-highlighter';
interface State {
    url: string;
    highlights: Array<IHighlight>;
}

const getNextId = () => String(Math.random()).slice(2);

const parseIdFromHash = () => document.location.hash.slice("#highlight-".length);

const resetHash = () => {
    document.location.hash = "";
};

const HighlightPopup = ({comment}: {comment: { text: string; emoji: string };}) => comment.text ? (
        <div className="Highlight__popup">
            {comment.emoji} {comment.text}
        </div>
    ) : null;

function PdfHighLighterPage() {
    const { isAuthenticated, loadUserFromCookies, user } = useAuth();
    const [highlights, setHighlights] = useState<Array<IHighlight>>([]);
    const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState("");
    const resetHighlights = () => {
        setHighlights([]);
    };


    let scrollViewerTo = (highlight: any) => { };

    const scrollToHighlightFromHash = () => {
        const highlight = getHighlightById(parseIdFromHash());

        if (highlight)  scrollViewerTo(highlight);
        
    };

    const getHighlightById = (id: string) => {
        return highlights.find((highlight) => highlight.id === id);
    };

    const addHighlight = (highlight: NewHighlight) => {
        console.log("Saving highlight", highlight);
        const oldHighLights = [
            { ...highlight, id: getNextId() },
            ...highlights,
        ]
        setHighlights(oldHighLights);
        localStorage.setItem("highlights", JSON.stringify(oldHighLights));
    };

    const updateHighlight = (highlightId: string, position: Object, content: Object) => {
        console.log("Updating highlight", highlightId, position, content);
        const oldHighLights = (prevHighlights: IHighlight[]) =>
            prevHighlights.map((h) => {
                const {
                    id,
                    position: originalPosition,
                    content: originalContent,
                    ...rest
                } = h;
                return id === highlightId
                    ? {
                        id,
                        position: { ...originalPosition, ...position },
                        content: { ...originalContent, ...content },
                        ...rest,
                    }
                    : h;
            })
        setHighlights(oldHighLights);
        localStorage.setItem("highlights", JSON.stringify(oldHighLights));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const localHighlights = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highlights") || "[]");
        setHighlights(localHighlights);
        const handleHashChange = () => {
            scrollToHighlightFromHash();
        };

        window.addEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange, false);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange);
        };

    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="flex mx-10 mb-10">
            <Sidebar
                highlights={highlights}
                resetHighlights={resetHighlights}
                scrollToHighlightFromHash={scrollToHighlightFromHash}
                setPdfUrl={setPdfUrl}
            />
            <div 
                className='h-screen w-3/4 relative'
            >
                <PdfLoader url={pdfUrl} beforeLoad={<span className="animate-spin h-5 w-5 mr-3" />}>
                    {(pdfDocument) => (
                        <PdfHighlighter
                            pdfDocument={pdfDocument}
                            enableAreaSelection={(event) => event.altKey}
                            onScrollChange={resetHash}
                            // pdfScaleValue="page-width"
                            scrollRef={(scrollTo) => {
                                scrollViewerTo = scrollTo;
                                scrollToHighlightFromHash();
                            }}
                            onSelectionFinished={(
                                position,
                                content,
                                hideTipAndSelection,
                                transformSelection
                            ) => (
                                <Tip
                                    onOpen={transformSelection}
                                    onConfirm={(comment) => {
                                        addHighlight({ content, position, comment });
                                        hideTipAndSelection();
                                    }}
                                />
                            )}
                            highlightTransform={(
                                highlight,
                                index,
                                setTip,
                                hideTip,
                                viewportToScaled,
                                screenshot,
                                isScrolledTo
                            ) => {
                                const isTextHighlight = !Boolean(
                                    highlight.content && highlight.content.image
                                );

                                const component = isTextHighlight ? (
                                    <Highlight
                                        isScrolledTo={isScrolledTo}
                                        position={highlight.position}
                                        comment={highlight.comment}
                                    />
                                ) : (
                                    <AreaHighlight
                                        isScrolledTo={isScrolledTo}
                                        highlight={highlight}
                                        onChange={(boundingRect) => {
                                            updateHighlight(
                                                highlight.id,
                                                { boundingRect: viewportToScaled(boundingRect) },
                                                { image: screenshot(boundingRect) }
                                            );
                                        }}
                                    />
                                );

                                return (
                                    <Popup
                                        popupContent={<HighlightPopup {...highlight} />}
                                        onMouseOver={(popupContent) =>
                                            setTip(highlight, (highlight) => popupContent)
                                        }
                                        onMouseOut={hideTip}
                                        key={index}
                                    >
                                        {component}
                                    </Popup>
                                );
                            }}
                            highlights={highlights}
                        />
                    )}
                </PdfLoader>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PdfHighLighterPage
```